# Open 'Index' file in Chrome Cache

Tags: python, google-chrome, indexing, browser-cache

I find 'Index' file in the Chrome Cache directory, but I don't know how to open it, this file is quite important for me to analyse the cache, and I also find a useful cache software, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html, this is what I want to make, but there is no source code...Help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [forensics wiki](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) and [chromium dev wiki](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache#TOC-Index-File-Structure).

Maybe duplicate with : [Chrome cache analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470999/chrome-cache-analysis) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found following the links on parallel question here in Stackoverflow

http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache
http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/disk_cache/disk_format.h?view=markup

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.